# Android flat file vs SQLite for storing help

Tags: android, sqlite, flat-file

In my android application there is a number of operations that the user can do (~50). For each of these operations, I will write a small amount of text explaining how they work ('help'). The majority of these operations are self explanatory, so the user will rarely have to read the 'help'.

There are two methods that I could think of for displaying the help:

- When the help is needed, display the help for all of the operations and have the view automatically scroll to the location of the help required
- Just display the help for the operation required

Is there a normal way of doing this?

I am already storing a list of the operations in a SQLite database. Should I add the 'help' in a new column or should I store it in a flat text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it so not sure of the tradeoffs, but it might be interesting to contemplate storing the help as html with named anchors and opening it in a webview?